# Code to stationarize multiple columns in time series

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with a time series dataset and I was wondering if there is an efficient way of differencing multiple time series columns in a data frame at once. For instance, we can use a for loop to apply .diff() in a column with a unit root (non-stationary series) and then attach the differenced column to the original dataset. Here is a snapshot of the dataset:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q58k9.png)

The dataset has a date column on the left side, followed by the names of the macroeconomic variables such as FCI, IPI, CPI.

I want to do the following in a data frame called df:

(1) difference the columns named - FCI, CSI, IPI, using .diff()

(2) Save the differenced values in 3 new columns and name them as FCI_diff, CSI_diff, IPI_diff

(3) Merge the 3 new columns into the original data frame.

I'd appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: _I struggle at iterating operations over multiple columns and for loops in general. So, I'd appreciate any help._ Can you be more specific? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic]. _Here is a snapshot of the dataset:_ Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Comment: I have edited the question and briefly written what the dataset contains.

Comment: _I have edited the question and briefly written what the dataset contains._ Where? Please see [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is @Igor's code packed in a single line:

```
df = pd.concat([df, df[["FCI", "CSI", "IPI"]].diff().add_suffix("_diff")], axis=1)
```

Comment: No problem. Bump me up then ;)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want to do exactly, but

```
df2 = df[["FCI", "CSI", "IPI"]].diff().add_suffix("_diff")
df3 = pd.concat([df, df2], axis=1)
```

Comment: thanks, Igor. that answered my question very well and the code worked!